# NullPointerException when trying to broadcast in side the mapPartitionsWithIndex

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nullpointerexception, broadcast

I am trying to broadcast array inside the **mapPartitionsWithIndex** function but this throws NullPointerException. Here is my code

```scala
var bestSolutions = bcWrapper(sc, (Array(): Array[BAT1], 3: Int)) //
  rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (index, iterator) =>
    var li = iterator.toArray
    var arr1 = arr.sortWith(_ < _).take(5)
    val selected = (arr1, index)
    bestSolutions.update(selected)
  }
```

definition of **bcWrapper** is

```scala
case class bcWrapper[T: ClassTag](@transient sc: SparkContext,
                                    @transient _v: T)
      extends Serializable {

    var broadcasted: Broadcast[T] = sc.broadcast(_v)
    def update(v: T): Unit = {
      try {
        broadcasted.destroy()
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          println("broadcast cannot be destroyed", e)
      }
      broadcasted = sc.broadcast(v)
    }
    def value: T = broadcasted.value
  }
```

Code throws exception when I call **update** function of **bcWrapper** class. How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to update or destroy a broadcasted object from `map` / `mapPartitions` code. Only read it. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to select some N elements from each partition and zip partition number and than want to broadcast those.

Comment: Why do you want to broadcast the result? Does `(rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (index ,iterator) =>
     val li = iterator.toArray
     val arr1 =arr.sortWith(_ < _).take(5)
     Iterator.single((index, arr1))
   }).collect` work for you?

Comment: collect will cause too much network traffic and will lead to performance loss